# Условие при размере экрана. JS

Tags: javascript

Как получить ширину экрана и сделать условие. Если ширина экрана (в px) меньше чем 600, то не выполнять скрипт.

Comment: `window.onresize = function (e) {console.log(e.target.outerWidth, e.target.outerHeight)}` - дальше сами разберетесь, я думаю

Comment: window.onresize срабатывает только если изменяется размер экрана, просто так он не срабатывает, соответственно не срабатывают и условия внутри функции

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что понимаю что именно вы хотите поэтому дам 2 ссылки

[ширина экрана `window.screen.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)

[ширина окна браузера `window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

```
 if( window.innerWidth >= 600 ){
      //выполнять
 } else {
      //не выполнять
 }
```